# comparisons using a hashMap not giving expected result

Tags: java, android, dictionary, comparison

The problem at hand is that when i try to pull the value from the `hashmap` it is returning null.

I have a `hashMap` instance :

`Map<Marker,Tag> theHashMap = new HashMap<Marker,Tag>();`

where tag is a class that holds some simple information about the `marker` and the `marker` is a Google map `marker`.

I add to theHashMap at the start of the activity that this all happens in

```
theHashMap.put(mapController.AddMarker(new Tag(1, "City Of Dundee", DUNDEE_LOCATION, "untagged",), new Tag(1, "City Of Dundee", DUNDEE_LOCATION, "untagged",));
```

where `mapController` is a class that deals with everything `googleMap` related.

And `mapController`.`AddMarker` returns the `marker` that was added to the map.

after the `hashMap` is filled it is passed to the `onMarkerClickListener` for later reference.

I call 
`hashMap.get(marker);` from within a `marker listener` where `marker` is the `marker` that was clicked.

It always returns null, I thought it may be because the `hashMap` inside the onMarkerClick listener was a separate instance but I tried making a pointer to the original and it didn't work, i also tried `hashMap.get(marker.getTitle());` and with the `marker.getID()` thinking that it would compare there titles but it ended with the same result.

I'll add more information if requested but for now, is there any other way of taking the value from the hashMap based on the marker that was clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `hashMap.put(marker,key);` here in this hashMap you have used key -> custom obje ct(mapper).

Hence it returns null when you called by the key. where `provide key (mapper)` object should match `with put (mapper) key.`

You have to **override equals and hashcode methods** in Mapper class to solve this.

**EDIT:**

In `HashMap` your `key` is `mapper object(custom object)`. As custom object(Mapper object) is key in HashMap we have to `override` equals and `hashcode` in `Mapper class` to fetch exact value.

```
If key as Primitives(int) or String Object, no need to do the above thing.
```

Comment: Sorry i'm struggling to understand what you mean, in `theHashMap.put(marker key, Tag value)` the key is a custom object, so  does that mean it expects an int, String etc instead of a custom object?